# xcb-xrm not found when installing polybar

Tags: 18.04, compiling, make, libraries

I have installed polybar and most parts of it is working, except for reading `Xresources`.

I do get a nice error message like this one

```
warn: No built-in support to dereference ${xrdb:color15:#555} references (requires `xcb-util-xrm`)
```

and it sounds rather straightforward. Just install it and it should be fine.
But I've installed `libxcb-xrm-dev` and I still get the same issues.

So I thought that maybe I have to recompile polybar, but it is not working(it compiles but no change). and what is interesting is that it doesn't seem to find `xcb-xrm` when compiling.

```
** Executing cmake command

-- Trying to enable ccache
-- Couldn't locate ccache, disabling ccache...
-- No build type specified; using RelWithDebInfo
-- Using supported compiler GNU-7.3.0
--  Build:
--    Type: RelWithDebInfo
--    CC: /usr/bin/gcc  -O2 -g -DNDEBUG
--    CXX: /usr/bin/g++  -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wno-noexcept-type -pedantic -pedantic-errors -O2 -g -DNDEBUG
--    LD: /usr/bin/ld  
--  Targets:
-- [X]   polybar-msg
-- [ ]   testsuite
--  Module support:
-- [X]   alsa (1.1.3)
-- [X]   curl (7.58.0)
-- [X]   i3
-- [X]   mpd (2.11)
-- [X]   network (wireless-tools)
-- [X]   pulseaudio (11.1)
-- [ ]   xkeyboard
--  X extensions:
-- [X]   xcb-randr (1.13)
-- [ ]   xcb-randr (monitor support)
-- [ ]   xcb-render
-- [ ]   xcb-damage
-- [ ]   xcb-sync
-- [X]   xcb-composite (1.13)
-- [ ]   xcb-xkb
-- [ ]   xcb-xrm
-- [ ]   xcb-cursor
```

So why wouldn't it find `xcb-xrm` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this problem. I see you are using the `build.sh` script. Here the easiest way is to pass the `-f` flag to the script when running it, like so: `build.sh -f`

This will force polybar to completely reconfigure itself and thus also detect the xrm dependency.

If you are not using the `build.sh` script, the remaining two ways are to either

- Delete the `build` dir (this is what `build.sh -f` also does) and run `cmake` and `make` again
- When running `cmake`, additionally pass the `-DWITH_XRM=ON` flag, this will force enable xrm support. If you are familiar with it, you can also use `cmake` to change the `WITH_XRM` variable to `ON`